# Is there a new wave of junk post and should I flag them as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I just found several low-quality posts that are obviously not programming-related.

1. [How many states in india](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975578/how-many-states-in-india)
2. [Ethical hacker and software Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975567/ethical-hacker-and-software-engineer)
3. [Summarize your problem in a one-line title. Describe your problem in more detail. Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975687/summarize-your-problem-in-a-one-line-title-describe-your-problem-in-more-detail)
4. [History of America](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975681/history-of-america)
5. [How to get iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975680/how-to-get-iphone)

Out of the above questions, I only flagged number 3 as spam; since it is the only post that contains a phone number. Nevertheless, all posts are just filled with craps.

Questions:

1. Is there a "spam" wave?
2. Should I use spam flag on them? Or should I use abusive (or other) flag?

Comment: #4 is a direct copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77975284/9473764) so definitely abusive. #3 is definitely spam. #1 and #5 look like spam seeds. #2 is perhaps just misguided.

Comment: It seems they've all been cleaned up now.

Comment: Who is promising free iPhones out there? There is also [a Discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/77976086/here-for-free-iphone) ([screenshot for when it gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzP7F.png))

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, those caught my eye as well. Not found the source of that misinformation yet. Might just be a clever prank.

Comment: I would flag any of these as spam. I did a few of those iPhone posts today.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a constant wave of "junk" posts. I wouldn't call it new but it might flare up now and then causing it to be seen by more users.

[image: graphs from Metasmoke]
<sup>[*Screenshot from the Meta Smoke dashboard*](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/)</sup>

The majority of these posts get detected by [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/smokey/) (or [manually reported](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65158712)) and subsequently send to various chatrooms across the Stack Exchange network where regular users will judge and cast flags.

When you run across 'junk' posts and are unsure if a flag is warranted you can always post a message in the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), using this template:

> `Hey, is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975578) spam?`

The room has an extensive [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) that layout what can and can't go in the room. It is also one of the chatrooms that receive Smokey's spam reports.

The posts you linked to all qualify to be removed, if not by spam and/or rude/abusive flags, then by close and delete votes. Feel free to bring similar posts to our attention.

Comment: What's the time zone for the hourly chart? I assume `12:00` means noon in that time zone, rather than midnight?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the [timezone seems to be UTC](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/data/sql/queries/325-time-on-ms) on the MariaDB server but I can't find anything if the application runs in a different zone.  This is where the graph gets inserted but I'm not a RoR dev so do not understand what comes next: https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/metasmoke/blob/master/app/views/dashboard/new_dash.html.erb#L74

Comment: If you change the time zone on your computer and refresh the page, the time of the last observation changes. Because of that, I think the chart is being displayed in the browser's time zone.

Comment: I'm mainly just wondering about attempts to geolocate the primary source of such questions. It might be instructive.